# Mongodb - convert the datetime to ISOdate format

Tags: mongodb

I want to convert the existing string date to new ISO date format. I used some scripts but they are not good enough to convert the time associated to the date. For ex: 2013-01-10 12:22:22 AM converted to ISODate("2013-01-10T06:00:00Z"). Here the time was not converting. Please help.

```
var cursor = db.customer.find({"created_at": {"$exists": true, "$type": 2 }}); 
while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
      var doc = cursor.next(); 
      var parts = doc.created_at.split("-");
      var dt = new Date(
            parseInt(parts[0], 10), // year
            parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1, // month
            parseInt(parts[2], 10)// day

        );
   db.customer.update(
    {"_id": doc._id}, 
    {"$set": {"created_at": dt}}
   ) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use new ISODate() :

```
new ISODate("2013-01-10 12:22:22 AM ")
ISODate("2013-01-10T12:22:22Z")
```

In your full example :

```
var cursor = db.customer.find({"created_at": {"$exists": true, "$type": 2 }}); 
while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
   var doc = cursor.next(); 
   db.customer.update(
    {"_id": doc._id}, 
    {"$set": {"created_at": new ISODate(doc.created_at)}}
   ) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, with above I was able to update the dates with delimiter -. I wasn't able to update the dates like '2013/01/10 12:22:22 AM'. Please advise

Comment: You can also use js Date type in your mongodb request (it will be cast to ISODate). new Date("2013/01/10 12:22:22 AM") will work.

Comment: new Date converting the date but it going to the default date of 1970-01-01:00:00:00. Not really helping me out.

Comment: I am getting the error, ISODate is not defined! Do I need to download something?